# Express-Session cookie won't update

Tags: javascript, express, express-session

Hello I am using working with express.js and currently I am stuck with express-sessions. My express session is sat up like this (index.js):

```
app.use(
  session({
  secret: 'idegas',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: null,
    user_identification: null,
    authorized: false,
  }
}))
```

When user is on login page and when user logins successfully I want to give them a session. Now I do that using this(login.js):

```
req.session.cookie.expires = new Date(Date.now() + '7200000')
req.session.cookie.user_identification = id
req.session.cookie.authorized = true
```

After this user gets redirected to dashboard and when I want to check users session it writes it back like this(console):

```
Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: null,
    originalMaxAge: null,
    httpOnly: true,
    user_identification: null,
    authorized: false
  }
}
```

As you can see nothing has changed. I'm very confused why this won't work. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[req.session.cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#user-content-reqsessioncookie)

> Each session has a unique cookie object accompany it. This allows you to alter the session cookie per visitor. For example we can set req.session.cookie.expires to false to enable the cookie to remain for only the duration of the user-agent.

This property is used to alter the behaviour of the session cookie.

It can't be used to add / change any other cookie

You want to use [res.cookie](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.cookie)

Comment: But will this apply to cookie that is inside my express-session??

Comment: Why would you like to edit your session cookie?

Comment: I want to have cookie that will store data like user_id and if user is authorized. I want that to be stored server-side so no one can change or edit it.

Comment: You are changing cookie properties instead of cookie data. You should just assign things to `req.session`

Comment: Well are that cookie properties different for every user or are they always same??

Comment: `req.session` is a different object for each user. `req.session.cookie` is like changing a file name instead of changing a file content.

Comment: But when I do something like this: 
`req.session.expires = new Date(Date.now() + '32400000')`

It still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

`req.session.cookie` property is used to set expiry date of the session (stored on the server) not sessionId cookie stored in user's browser.

you can set `req.session.cookie.expires = false` to make session expire immidietly (then it will be a session cookie, that will be delete when server restarts). if you want to set a specific expiry date, then use `req.session.cookie.maxAge` property instead (as it is not recommended to set date to `expires` property directly).

if you want this expiry date to be set on sessionId cookie (stored in user's browser) also then you have to set `rolling: true` option in the session middleware.

**Note:**

- `req.session.cookie` is not meant to be used as cookie to store data, so store data on the session itself, ex: `req.session.user_identification = id`
- If both `expires` and `maxAge` are set in the options (or as properties), then the last one defined in the object is what is used.